# Online SharePoint List Sending Email to Assigned To

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hi we are trying to trigger an email to each user who is "Assigned To" in one of our SharePoint Online lists. We are not seeking approved from "Assigned To" user; we want the "Assigned To" user to be notified of the assignment with an email and link to the record. I looked through many templates but did not find anything that met our requirement for SharePoint Online. Can you tell me is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In the old days that was an option on a task list but on a generic list you will have to add some kind of workflow to do that. A Flow is most likely the future proof option

Comment: Flow is the best choice for it but you could use a more classic approach (I don't prefer it) using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Thank you Kasper Bo Larsen and jaloplo for the answers.